# How to install/run World Of Warcraft on Ubuntu 12.04.1?

Tags: installation, games

On my Windows 7 I have a game called 'World Of Warcraft'.... And because I don't use Windows I want to install World Of Warcraft on my Ubuntu But the problem it I don't know how... I have a Winrar file with the original game itself and I don't know what to do with it. I have the 'Play On Linux' App installed too... but what do I do?

Does anybody know how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Wine. Then you install play on Linux, and then install your game. You will find this things in Ubuntu software center.

Comment: Yes i have the Play on linux app but i have a zip file with the whole game... do i just select that?

Comment: you have to unzip the file - ubuntu does it for you when you click the file - and then extract. You have to install with the install file (setup.exe or something like that)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Crossover from Codeweavers. It't the commercial version of wine. [Link Here](http://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility/browse/name/?app_id=7714) Download and install crossover, then download and click the crosstie. Everything else should be automatic.

Fair warning, I advocate for them, not sure it matters but just disclosing.